# Purging Vista from Ubuntu that's partitioned; mechanism and how to

Tags: installation, dual-boot, partitioning, hard-drive, windows-vista

Im a recent convert to Ubuntu.  When I installed Ubuntu, I did it alongside of
existing Vista.  (Before that, a friend partitioned my HD to make room).
Im so satisfied with Ubuntu that I'm getting rid of Vista gradually.
Currently, Vista is taking up 80G and 50G is free. Another 80G or so is allocated for Ubuntu.

Now, its mechanism: Am I right to visualise that in my computer, Vista and Ubuntu
are like two separate rooms next to each other; so, if you clear out one room, that 
does not make room for the other room?  Or, is this still one room so that as I keep downloading with Ubuntu, it would make use of the free 50G space in Vista section automatically?

Is getting rid of the partition wall advisable (now that I have successfully installed
Ubuntu)? if possible?  Or is the partition still of some use? Thank you for your advice in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You are partially correct. You can think of Vista and Ubuntu as separate rooms. But say if you remove Vista you will be able to use newly freed space without any issue. Now it's upto you about what file system to use for this newly freed space. You can either use NTFS or EXT3 (or any Ubuntu supported format).

And I think, you can combine partitions wall as well if partitions belong to same group (Primary or Logical). For that try `gparted`, it has nice UI and it is very easy to use